# Why does my preg_replace() on multi-line file contents on Windows fail?

Tags: php, regex

I have a text file Qfile.txt and the contents are follows, and want to create another file with the same informations and but answers are diffrent. Qfile1.txt,Qfile2.txt

***Qfile.txt***

```
Question "What is your age?"
Answer ""

Question "What you doing?"
Answer ""

Question "What is you name?"
Answer ""
```

***Qfile1.txt***

```
Question "What is your age?"
Answer "25"

Question "What you doing?"
Answer "chatting"

Question "What is you name?"
Answer "Midhun"
```

I want to read the questions from the Qfile.txt and store the informations to Qfile1.txt
with in PHP. I wrote some code but the pattern matching is not working:

```
$contents=file_get_contents("Qfile.txt");
foreach(/*bla bla*/)
{
  $pattern = "/Question \"".preg_quote($id, '/')."\"\nAnswer \"\"/";

  $string = str_replace('"', '\"', $string);

  $replacement = "Question \"$id\"\nAnswer \"". $string . "\"";

  $result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $contents);
}
```

The `preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $contents);` is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unable to replicate; your code, suitably adapted, actually works fine for me.  The only thing I can think of is that perhaps you're writing this on a Windows machine and your text file has CRLF line terminators.  In that case, you'd need to change your code to:

```
$contents=file_get_contents("Qfile.txt");
foreach(/*bla bla*/)
{
  $pattern = "/Question \"".preg_quote($id, '/')."\"(\r?\n)Answer \"\"/";

  $string = str_replace('"', '\"', $string);

  $replacement = "Question \"$id\"$1Answer \"". $string . "\"";

  $result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $contents);
}
```

The changes are on the `$pattern =` and `$replacement =` lines.  I've written it so that it will preserve whichever line termination pattern is in place (out of the two it supports, LF and CRLF).

Comment: That's your problem, then.  Modify your code per above and that should fix it.

Comment: Yup, should be fine on either platform.

Comment: You see in the `$pattern` where I made it do `(\r?\n)`?  That means "accept either `\r\n` or `\n`, and put whichever it is into `$1`".  That's how I made it compatible with both Windows and Linux; it stores whichever line termination pattern it found and re-uses it when it puts in your data.

Comment: Ok i understood it really very helpful, once again thank you mr chaos

Comment: You're welcome.  FYI, I'm translating "what `(\r?\n)` means" *very* loosely; when you have the chance, you should look into more about grouping / parenthesis capturing in PHP regular expressions.  This looks like a likely place: http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php