# using php preg_replace with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I created a php regex to find all comments /* */ in a string which works as I tested it using this test tool http://regexpal.com/

```
/\*(.*\s){0,}.*\*\/
```

I then surrounded it with delimiters # so it works with preg_replace however now it doesn't work.

```
#/\*(.*\s){0,}.*\*\/#

$fileContents = preg_replace("#/\*(.*\s){0,}.*\*\/#","Replacement Text",$fileContents);
```

When I echo out $fileContents nothing is printed out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like [it works for me](http://viper-7.com/cNZnqL). Do you have a test case that is failing?

Comment: Why does it look so complicated? You could just use `.*?` and the `#s` dotall modifier instead for the inner match.

Comment: tip: `{0,}` is the same as `*`. Did you check that `$fileContents` actually contains something BEFORE you feed it into preg_replace? Even if the regex didn't find anythign to replace, you should **AT LEAST** get back out the original string.

Comment: FileContents contains text before had which I echo out to check. When I add in var_dump to the preg_replace it outputs null.

Comment: just to let you know I figured it it out. There was an issue with the  CRLF line terminators. I used regex "#/\*(.\r?\n)*.*\*\/#"  See link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179349/why-does-my-preg-replace-on-multi-line-file-contents-on-windows-fail Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
  $fileContents = "Hello /* comment here */ World"; 
  $fileContents = preg_replace('#\/\*.*\*\/#m','',$fileContents); 
  echo $fileContents; // outputs Hello World

  $fileContents = <<<END
Hello
/*
 * Comment spanning several lines..
 *
 */
Earth
END;

  $fileContents = preg_replace('#\/\*.*\*\/#m','',$fileContents); 
  echo $fileContents; // outputs Hello Earth
?>
```

The `m` at the end of the regex will match "multi-line", so that when comment spans on several lines, it can still match them. Default match is single line.

See PCRE for your reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: That's not what `#m` does. It impacts how `^` and `$` match linebreaks instead of subject start and end.

Comment: When I use your example it works but when I replace the text with mine it doesn't?

Comment: Dexter probably means to use the `s` modifier to affect the `.` (to also match newlines).  As Mario said, the `m` is useless.